# Error al crear un Release de mi App Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una App con `AndroidStudio 2.1`
En modo Debut, corre bien y hace lo que debe hacer, pero en el momento de compilar en modo Release, no lo hace y manda los siguientes errores:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal o qué me falta por hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Habilita el soporte multidex dentro de tu `build.gradle` :

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Habilita soporte multidex.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

El error es causado porque la especificacion de un ejecutable Dalvik indica un limite del numero total de métodos que pueden ser referenciados en un archivo .DEX como 65,536, si tienes una cantidad mayor debes habilitar el soporte.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html